# Google Document commands standard

Tags: google-docs

I wrote some text in google doc offline and it fails to sync it.
Inspecting requests I found that it tries to do the sync process with a post request containing actions I've done while offline.
It's something like this:

{'commands': [{'ibi': 14223, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14224, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14225, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14226, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14227, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'si': 14228, 'ei': 14261, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'si': 14227, 'ei': 14227, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'si': 14226, 'ei': 14226, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'si': 14225, 'ei': 14225, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'si': 14224, 'ei': 14224, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'si': 14223, 'ei': 14223, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'si': 14222, 'ei': 14222, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'mts': [{'ibi': 14222, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'si': 14222, 'st': 'text', 'ei': 14222, 'sm': {'ts_it_i': True, 'ts_st_i': True, 'ts_fgc_i': True, 'ts_bd_i': True, 'ts_fs_i': True, 'ts_un_i': True, 'ts_ff_i': True, 'ts_va_i': True, 'ts_bgc_i': True, 'ts_sc_i': True}, 'ty': 'as'}], 'ty': 'mlti'}, {'ibi': 14223, 's': ';', 'ty': 'is'}, {'si': 14223, 'ei': 14223, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'mts': [{'ibi': 14223, 's': 'ک', 'ty': 'is'}, {'si': 14223, 'st': 'text', 'ei': 14223, 'sm': {'ts_it_i': True, 'ts_st_i': True, 'ts_fgc_i': True, 'ts_bd_i': True, 'ts_fs_i': True, 'ts_un_i': True, 'ts_ff_i': True, 'ts_va_i': True, 'ts_bgc_i': True, 'ts_sc_i': True}, 'ty': 'as'}], 'ty': 'mlti'}, {'ibi': 14224, 's': 'ه', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14225, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14226, 's': 'ر', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14227, 's': 'ف', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14228, 's': 'ت', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14229, 's': 'ه', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14230, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14231, 's': 'ر', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14232, 's': 'ف', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14233, 's': 'ت', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14234, 's': 'ه', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14235, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14236, 's': 'ب', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14237, 's': 'ع', 'ty': 'is'}, {'si': 14237, 'ei': 14237, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'mts': [{'ibi': 14237, 's': 'ه', 'ty': 'is'}, {'si': 14237, 'st': 'text', 'ei': 14237, 'sm': {'ts_it_i': True, 'ts_st_i': True, 'ts_fgc_i': True, 'ts_bd_i': True, 'ts_fs_i': True, 'ts_un_i': True, 'ts_ff_i': True, 'ts_va_i': True, 'ts_bgc_i': True, 'ts_sc_i': True}, 'ty': 'as'}], 'ty': 'mlti'}, {'ibi': 14238, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14239, 's': 'ت', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14240, 's': 'ع', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14241, 's': 'د', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14242, 's': 'ا', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14243, 's': 'د', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14244, 's': 'ش', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14245, 's': 'ا', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14246, 's': 'ن', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14247, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14248, 's': 'ا', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14249, 's': 'ف', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14250, 's': 'ز', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14251, 's': 'و', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14252, 's': 'د', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14253, 's': 'د', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14254, 's': 'ه', 'ty': 'is'}, {'si': 14254, 'ei': 14254, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'si': 14253, 'ei': 14253, 'ty': 'ds'}, {'mts': [{'ibi': 14253, 's': 'ه', 'ty': 'is'}, {'si': 14253, 'st': 'text', 'ei': 14253, 'sm': {'ts_it_i': True, 'ts_st_i': True, 'ts_fgc_i': True, 'ts_bd_i': True, 'ts_fs_i': True, 'ts_un_i': True, 'ts_ff_i': True, 'ts_va_i': True, 'ts_bgc_i': True, 'ts_sc_i': True}, 'ty': 'as'}], 'ty': 'mlti'}, {'ibi': 14254, 's': ' ', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14255, 's': 'م', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14256, 's': 'ی', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14257, 's': '\u200c', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14258, 's': 'ش', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14259, 's': 'د', 'ty': 'is'}, {'ibi': 14260, 's': '.', 'ty': 'is'}], 'reqId': 0, 'sid': 'e0e19c9076fbda5'}

How can I recover my text by this commands? what's its standard? does anybody knows a program that can parse it?
Does anybody know where does google-drive-offline store these command so that I can split it into small pieces?